# Issue of retriving data into javascript using checkbox

Tags: php, javascript, html

Ok,I have a data which i retrieve from database in the table format. Check-box is also there for each record. I am retriving data like this :

```
<tr>
   <td><input name="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" type="checkbox" class="check"></td>
   <td><center><?php echo htmlspecialchars_decode($row['id'], ENT_QUOTES); ?></center></td>
   <td><center><?php echo htmlspecialchars_decode($row['section'], ENT_QUOTES); ?></center></td>
   <td><center><?php echo htmlspecialchars_decode($row['chapter'], ENT_QUOTES); ?></center></td>
   <td style="padding-left:25px;margin:15px"><?php echo $_SESSION['question']=htmlspecialchars_decode($row['question'], ENT_QUOTES); ?></center></td>
   <td><center><?php echo htmlspecialchars_decode($row['correctAnswer'], ENT_QUOTES); ?></center></td>
   <td><center><?php echo htmlspecialchars_decode($row['category'], ENT_QUOTES); ?></center></td>
   <td><center><a href="<?php echo "Update.php?id=".$row['id']."&mode=update";?>"id="dialog_10">Update</a></center></td>
</tr>
```

Ok, Now i want to collect checked value or checked row in javascript for storing all checkedvalue in stored procedure mysql..But i dont understand how ??

Answer (score 0):

maybe something like this

```
var checkboxValue = null; 
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
for(var i=0; elements[i]; ++i){
      if(elements[i].className==="check" && 
         elements[i].checked){
           checkboxValue = elements[i].value;
           break;
      }
}
```

And add the value attribute to your checkbox.

Comment: Thank You andr3ina for reply..can i stored javascript(elements) values in stored procedure ???

Comment: I guess you could use AJAX.. http://www.w3resource.com/ajax/working-with-PHP-and-MySQL.php